# How to change dll folder location?

Tags: dll, d

I programming in D and my app needs to load libpq.dll. It's loading successfully. The problem that after runs my app trying to find libintl.dll. If I place it's in its bin folder it's run ok. The problem that I want to change its location and move it's to the \lib folder.

How can I do it?

I do not a thing that the second lib should be specified at compile time, but my code for loading first lib is next to ^

```
DerelictPQ.load(buildPath(getcwd ~ "\\libs\\libpq.dll"));
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the directory to the `PATH` environment variable before loading the DLLs?

Comment: you can read details about how Windows finds dlls here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications

Comment: Why do you want to move it to the lib folder anyway? The bin folder is often used for dlls in Windows (since that just works with the system rules) so it wouldn't be weird to leave it there and then you don't have to fight the system.

Comment: I know about `PATH`. But ok, thanks, look like it's more easier to mix dlls with bin.